# Estimating pi by throwing darts

Tags: java, pi

Essentially i want to find an estimate of pi by throwing a dart at the unit circle. So I want to throw a dart a the positive x and y quadrant of the unit circle , each dart thrown will give me a random position in the x and y direction that is less that 1. I then need to find the distance from the origin from that point. The approximation of pi will come from when the distance of the dart from the origin is less than 1 when calculated, this will count as a hit, anything else will count as a miss. Using this number pi is found by (#hits/#of tosses)*4 since i will only be looking at 1/4 of the circle .I then want to print a table with different results depending on how many darts are thrown. my code is below, I'm confused on a lot of things, mainly how do I collect all the data and print it all, I was thinking of using an ArrayList of arrays of ints since it will not be limited to the amount of trials I want to do but I am unsure on how to proceed. Any help is useful, thanks!

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    
    int[] darts_Thrown = {10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000,1000000};
    

   

  //  for( int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
   //     System.out.print(points[i]);
  //  }



   for (int i = 0; i < darts_Thrown.length;i++){
        
       for (int j = 0; j < darts_Thrown[i]; j++){
        int test = 0;
        double [] points = getPoint();
       // distanceToOrigin(points[0],points[1]);
       // getHits();
       test++;
       System.out.printf("%d",test);
       }
       System.out.printf("%n%s", "hi ");
   }
   
}
public static double[] getPoint()//code to generate x and y and return them in a double array
{
    
    double[] point_X_Y = {Math.random(),Math.random()};

    return point_X_Y;
    
    
}
public static double distanceToOrigin(double x,double y) //code to compute distance from point (x,y) to origin (0,0)
{
   
    
    double distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x,2))+(Math.pow(y,2))); // used to find distance from origin
   
    return distance;
    
    
}
public static int getHits(int n)
{
    int hits = 0;
    int misses=0;
    
//double distance = distanceToOrigin(points[0], points[1]);
    //if (distance < 0){
  //      hits++;
   //     return hits;
  //  }
  //  else{
   //     misses++;
    //return misses;
  //  }
   // return 0;
    //code to get hits given n= number of darts
}
```

}

Comment: For one thing your distance formula is wrong. For another thing, your origin (in the way you are generating random points) is .5,.5

Comment: Start small, and more verbose: have a method `RunResult throwDarts(int darts) { ... }` that runs your algorithm for that many darts, and track each thing you want to track during the run in its own list/array, then return an object that you can assign all the values you care about, e.g. `class RunResult { int dartsThrown, hits, misses; public RunResult(...) { ... }}`. Then in your main function you can capture those results in an `ArrayList<RunResult>` or the like. Make methods do one thing: `throwDarts` throws darts by calling `boolean throwDart() { ... } ` as many times as needed, etc

Comment: **"pi is found by (#hits/#of tosses)"**.  If that's true, then you're going to have to hit the right part of the square a little more than 3 times, on average, each time you throw a dart.  That would be quite a trick in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula `#hits/#tosses` is correct in thought, but it's gotta be too small, since it can't possibly be larger than 1.  It turns out that that formula will approximate the value of `PI/4`, so the approximation of PI is `#hits/#tosses*4`.

For each trial, it isn't really practical to "collect all the data and print it all", if you want to get a reasonable approximation of PI by the end, because it's going to take a million or so trials to get at all close.  I found that 1M trials gives a pretty good result, and 10M often gives you the right result to 4 decimal places.  There's no use in printing even a few 100 individual trials, much less 1M of them.  So I think all you can really print is the trial number, the number of throws, the number of hits, and the final approximation of PI.  Here's code that does that:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        int[] darts_Thrown = {10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000};

        for (int i = 0; i < darts_Thrown.length;i++){

            int hits = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < darts_Thrown[i]; j++){
                double [] points = getPoint();
                double distance = distanceToOrigin(points[0],points[1]);
                if (distance <= 1.0)
                    hits++;
            }
            double pi_est = (double)hits / darts_Thrown[i] * 4.0;

            System.out.printf("Trial: %d  Throws: %d  Hits: %d  Approximation of PI (hits/throws*4): %.4f\n",
                    i, darts_Thrown[i], hits, pi_est);
        }

    }
    public static double[] getPoint()//code to generate x and y and return them in a double array
    {
        final double[] doubles = {Math.random(), Math.random()};
        return doubles;
    }
    public static double distanceToOrigin(double x,double y) //code to compute distance from point (x,y) to origin (0,0)
    {
        double distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x,2))+(Math.pow(y,2))); // used to find distance from origin
        return distance;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Trial: 1  Throws: 10  Hits: 8  Approximation of PI (hits/throws*4): 3.2000
Trial: 2  Throws: 100  Hits: 79  Approximation of PI (hits/throws*4): 3.1600
Trial: 3  Throws: 1000  Hits: 773  Approximation of PI (hits/throws*4): 3.0920
Trial: 4  Throws: 10000  Hits: 7800  Approximation of PI (hits/throws*4): 3.1200
Trial: 5  Throws: 100000  Hits: 78409  Approximation of PI (hits/throws*4): 3.1364
Trial: 6  Throws: 1000000  Hits: 785250  Approximation of PI (hits/throws*4): 3.1410
Trial: 7  Throws: 10000000  Hits: 7852455  Approximation of PI (hits/throws*4): 3.1410
```

The formula is pretty easy to derive.  For a circle with radius 1 centered at the origin, 1/4 of it will be in the quadrant x=0-1, y=0-1.  The points inside that circle are 1 unit from the origin or closer, so those are all 'hits'.  A 1/4 of a circle of radius 1 has an area of PI * r^2 / 4 = PI * 1^2 / 4 = PI/4. The entire target area is x * y = 1 * 1 = 1.  So hits/throws = (PI/4)/(1) = PI/4. Multiply both sides by 4 to get `PI = hits/throws * 4`.

Comment: I wish i could just do it like that but i need to do it in a table with multiple attempts to show the accuracy of the calculation. so would the way that i was going about it going to work if i keep at it ?

Comment: Sure.  I'm sorry.  I thought this was a fun idea, so I admit that I partly just wanted to implement it myself and see how well it predicted PI.  So I wasn't thinking about your requirements enough maybe.  Use whatever you can from what I've given you.  I'd be happy to help you further to get you to where you want to be.  Have you gotten any further along than what you have in your question?  If so, you could update your question maybe.

Comment: Where are you stumbling now with this?  Do you really want/need to print every trial.  I can see doing bigger and bigger trials and showing how the approximation gets better and better.  It doesn't matter.  If you want to show each trial, that's just one line of code.

Comment: all good lmao. I realized it wasnt java, but like all code is the same syntax so i understood. I want to be able to print out a table starting with a low number of trials to a large number, so like 10 - 1000000. I havent had the time to work on the problem so im still in the same spot. Mainly my main concern is how to i take the information from my methods, mainly the array that contains the random numbers and store them?

Comment: Wow.  I was really out of it last night.  I even used the wrong language on you.  Sorry... - So I posted something new, in Java this time and using your code as a basic framework.  I wasn't sure what you were doing with `getHits`, so I left that out for now.

Comment: It would be easy to add storing the numbers.  I guess even at 10M trials, the computers we have these days can hold onto that pretty easily.  So do you want to compute all of the points first, and then run back through them to calculate hits/misses and come up with the PI approximation?  What do you really want to display?  Is what is here now closer?

Comment: Right now i have a nested for loop to read in the number of trials i want to do and then i have it create an array with 2 random numbers. Should i create a array list of my array of random points and then take that array list and put it as a parameter for my next method which calculated the distance? I really am just confused on how i should go about doing the whole multiple trial thing

Comment: Did you look at my new code?  It does multiple trials using your counts for each trial.  It just doesn't store all of the points and then later do something with them.  Rather, it just tallies up the number of hits by using each trial and then throwing away the point.  But you could store all the points first and do this in two stages. - It uses your original loops

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223831/discussion-between-david-wood-and-steve).